# remove "wrench force" floor bike pump from the schrader valve

Tags: pump, schrader

It is embarrassing for me to say the number of tubes I have destroyed removing the chuck. Are there techniques or adapters I am missing? Or do I have a defective chuck?

Comment: Can you put a picture of a destroyed tube? It was somewhat plausible with on frame pumps to destroy tubes due to movement of the valve stem due to the pumping action (hence the new ones having little hoses to avoid the pump transmit force to the valve stem). But on most pumps, you just pull the chuck straight off in the direction pointed to by the valve stem after unlocking the chuck. I have never had an issue with a track pump (e.g. the Topeak JoeBlow Sport ii I currently use) in regards to tube damage.

Comment: After filling the tube, I put the handle back in the original position and try to pull the truck off. I just do not have the strength in my fingers and hands to pull it off. I have tried to use tools to extend my strength but with the same result. The valve separates from the tube or tears right at the flat part of the tube (where the valve and tube connect). Could I be putting on too far? Is there a lubricant that could be applied?

Comment: It sounds like you have a defective chuck.  (One thing to note, however, is that some chucks lock by flipping up the lever, others lock by pressing it down.  It may be that you're inflating with the chuck unlocked and then trying to pull it off locked.)

Comment: Daniel, you are exactly correct. The chuck was defective and when I replaced the chuck and the connecting tube everything is easy and works nicely. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you discovered (see comments), your chuck was defective/broken.

(Please consider closing this question.)